# I found these skulls in a old bottle in the woods. Can you tell me what they are?

Tags: zoology, species-identification

[image: top and bottom of skull]
[image]

Can you help me identify these skulls I found in an old bottle in the woods?

Comment: That top photo looks like a shrew skull.

Comment: Where and in what type of environment did you find them?

Comment: I found them in a bottle that I picked up in the woods in Illinois.

Comment: Why they were put inside bottle? Could there be archaeological significance?

Answer (score 4):

Its a Shrew skull.

[image]

[Hainault Forest Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPTzz.jpg)

Photographs by © Brian Ecott